# I use a php fsockopen to send a mail but it fails

Tags: php, email

the code is :

```
function logit($txt) {
        $log = fopen('/tmp/mail.txt','a+');;
        fwrite($log,$txt."\n");
        fclose($log);
    }

    function SendMail($ServerName, $Port, $ToEmail, $FromEmail, $Subject, $Body, $Header = '', $Username = '', $Password = '') {

        $smtp = fsockopen($ServerName, $Port);
        $InputBuffer = fgets($smtp, 1024);
        $GECode=220;
        if (substr($InputBuffer,0,3) != $GECode) {
            logit('Connect:'.$InputBuffer);
            fclose($smtp);
            return FALSE;
        }

        fputs($smtp, "HELO $ServerName\n");
        $InputBuffer = fgets($smtp, 1024);
        $GECode=250;
        if (substr($InputBuffer,0,3) != $GECode) {
            fclose($smtp);
            logit('HELO:'.$InputBuffer);
            return FALSE;
        }


        if ($Username != '') {
            fputs($smtp,"AUTH LOGIN\n");
            $smtpResponse = fgets($smtp, 1024);
            $GECode=250;
            if (substr($InputBuffer,0,3) != $GECode) {
                fclose($smtp);
                logit('AUTH'.$InputBuffer);
                return FALSE;
            }


            if ($Username != '') {
                fputs($smtp, base64_encode($Username)."\n");
                $smtpResponse = fgets($smtp, 1024);
                $GECode=250;
                if (substr($InputBuffer,0,3) != $GECode) {
                    fclose($smtp);
                    logit($InputBuffer);
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }

            if ($Password != '') {
                fputs($smtp, base64_encode($Password)."\n");
                $smtpResponse = fgets($smtp, 1024);
                $GECode=250;
                if (substr($InputBuffer,0,3) != $GECode) {
                    fclose($smtp);
                    logit($InputBuffer);
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }
        }


        fputs($smtp, "MAIL From:<$FromEmail>\n");
        $InputBuffer = fgets($smtp, 1024);
        $GECode=250;
        if (substr($InputBuffer,0,3) != $GECode) {
            fclose($smtp);
            logit($InputBuffer);
            return FALSE;
        }


        fputs($smtp, "RCPT To:<$ToEmail>\n");
        $InputBuffer = fgets($smtp, 1024);
        $GECode=250;
        if (substr($InputBuffer,0,3) != $GECode) {
            fclose($smtp);
            logit($InputBuffer);
            return FALSE;
        }

        fputs($smtp, "DATA\n");
        $InputBuffer = fgets($smtp, 1024);
        $GECode=354;
        if (substr($InputBuffer,0,3) != $GECode) {
            fclose($smtp);
            logit($InputBuffer);
            return FALSE;
        }


        fputs($smtp, "From: $FromEmail\n");
        fputs($smtp, "To: $ToEmail\n");
        if ($Header != '') {
            fputs($smtp, "$Header");
        }
        fputs($smtp, "Subject: $Subject\n\n");
        fputs($smtp, "$Body\r\n.\r\n");
        fputs($smtp, "QUIT\n");
        $InputBuffer = fgets($smtp, 1024);
        $GECode=250;
        if (substr($InputBuffer,0,3) != $GECode) {
            fclose($smtp);
            logit($InputBuffer);
            return FALSE;
        }

        fclose($smtp);
        return TRUE;
    }

    $server = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com ';
    $port = 465;

$email='oil_karchack@yahoo.com';    
$subject='test subject';
$body='test body';
SendMail($server,$port,'shervin_445@yahoo.com',$email,$subject,$body,$headers,'email','pass');
```

also i use mail function that doesn't send mail neither

Comment: Have you checked the error logs? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: headers in /home/newnewsw/public_html/contactus.php on line 179

Comment: Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/newnewsw/public_html/contactus.php on line 73

Comment: $server = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com' - have you tried it with just the server name. i.e 'smtp.gmail.com'? i am not sure that 'ssl://' is a valid url scheme.

Comment: Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com :465 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known) in /home/newnewsw/public_html/contactus.php on line 73

Comment: Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/newnewsw/public_html/contactus.php on line 74

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/newnewsw/public_html/contactus.php on line 78

Comment: Now that you know what the errors are you can start trouble-shooting. Clearing up one error will likely clean up others.

Comment: i changed the smtp server to smtp.gmail.com and also changed the port to 587 still the same error what should i use for the server and port ?

Comment: sorry it had one space in it and it didn't work, now it does not show any error with the $server = 'smtp.gmail.com';$port = 587 ; but the email does not deliver

Comment: I see in https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en that only 2000 msg per day can be sent using google smtp server, it's not enough for me how can i send email without smtp server ? the mail function doesn't send mail in my host

Comment: I Used phpmailer but still the mail doesn't deliver the code is :

Comment: require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->setFrom($email, 'First Last');
  $mail->addReplyTo('shervin_445@yahoo.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->addAddress('shervin_445@yahoo.com', 'John Doe');
  $mail->Subject = $subject;
  $mail->msgHTML($body, dirname(__FILE__));

Comment: $mail->AltBody = $body;
  if (!$mail->send()) {
   $resultMsg=$mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
   $resultMsg='Your message received successfully';
  }

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment as i need the space.

It is to confirm the setting actually needed to send an email via the 'google' smtp server. [Google Apps SMTP settings to send mail from a printer, scanner, or app](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)

I use 'SwiftMailer' [Free Feature-rich PHP Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) as the PHP Mail software. 'PhpMailer' is also reliable mailer software. I have used both.

I use the *'SSL'* encryption option when sending the message so i use port: *465*. If using 'TLS' encryption then use port: *587*

Here are the settings i use - 'PhpMailer' will have similar settings -  (rubbish username and password):

```
Transport: 
    ->setHost('smtp.gmail.com')
    ->setPort(465)
    ->setEncryption('ssl')
    ->setTimeout(20)
    ->setUsername('not.valid@gmail.com')
    ->setPassword('not.valid.password!);
```

Here is the complete log of the 'send' (note the 'OK' reply):

```
<< 220 mx.google.com ESMTP ha10sm2282960wjc.37 - gsmtp

>> EHLO [127.0.0.1]

<< 250-mx.google.com at your service, [123.123.123.123]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8

>> AUTH LOGIN
<< 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
>> zmZ2MTIzLnX123XN0aW9uc0BnbWFpbC5jb20=
<< 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
>> ZmluRTY12tpdGUlMDAx

<< 235 2.7.0 Accepted

++ Swift_SmtpTransport started
>> MAIL FROM: <questions@not.valid.uk>

<< 250 2.1.0 OK ha10sm2282960wjc.37 - gsmtp

>> RCPT TO: <not.valid@hotmail.com>

<< 250 2.1.5 OK ha10sm2282960wjc.37 - gsmtp

>> DATA
<< 354  Go ahead ha10sm2282960wjc.37 - gsmtp
>> 
.
<< 250 2.0.0 OK 1426244335 ha10sm2282960wjc.37 - gsmtp
```